# How to deal with errno and signal handler in Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, signal-handling

When we write a signal handler that may change the errno, should we save errno at the beginning of the signal handler and restore the errno at the end of it? Just like below:

```
void signal_handler(int signo){
    int temp_errno = errno;
    *** //code here may change the errno
    errno = temp_errno;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The glibc documentation [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/POSIX-Safety-Concepts.html):

> signal handlers that call functions that may set errno or modify the floating-point environment must save their original values, and restore them before returning.

So go ahead and do that.

If you're writing a multi-threaded program using pthreads, there's a workaround that requires less effort. `errno` will be in thread-local storage. If you dedicate one thread to handle process-directed signals, blocking the signal in all other threads, you don't have to worry about assignments to `errno` in the signal handler.

Comment: Why don't nearly all signal handlers save errno and restore it in single thread process? Because these programmers just don't take this into consideration?

Comment: In addition the man page signal-safety(7) says this: "Fetching and setting the value of errno is async-signal-safe
       provided that the signal handler saves errno on entry and
       restores its value before returning."